# Can nouns take more than one argument?

Tags: semantics, linguistics

In semantic analysis, are n-predicate nouns, n>1, a formally accepted thing?

When could a noun be n-predicate?

I think of *Friend* as a 2-predicate noun: *friend'(x, y)* means that x thinks of y as a friend. I guess this means that *He is my friend* is not semantically "He is mine, and he is a friend"? That makes senses to me. Are there any problems with this? Or any other analyses?

What's the general contemporary consensus?

Comment: In effect, it's a kinship term, and they are relations between two NPs. Logically, "my friend" would be FRIEND (I, X), where X is a human NP and I is me. Nouns can have complements, like NP complements with picture nouns - _the claim [that Bill won the election]_ -- and they can refer to relations in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> In effect, it's a kinship term, and they are relations between two NPs. Logically, "my friend" would be FRIEND (I, X), where X is a human NP and I is me. Nouns can have complements, like NP complements with picture nouns - *the claim [that Bill won the election]* -- and they can refer to relations in many ways.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but my question was "is this a generally-accepted approach among modern day semantic analysis?" Do you have references or citations that back this up? _The claim **that Bill won the election**_ is definitely an example of a syntactic complement, but that doesn't mean it has to be a semantic argument (as far as I know)